# Implementing a custom view and a ScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-custom-view

Here is what I don't understand:

```
    HorizontalScrollView scroll = new HorizontalScrollView(this);       
    scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_hand_width), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_hand_height)));

    HandLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    HandLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    HandLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_hand));
    HandLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_hand_width), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_hand_height)));
    scroll.addView(HandLayout);


    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setWidth(200);
        HandLayout.addView(b);
     }
```

This shows the ScrollView with all 8 buttons and it is scrollable.
However, when I replace the last few lines with:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        HeroCard hc = new HeroCard(this);
        HandLayout.addView(hc);
    }
```

Then nothing shows. HeroCard is a custom view that just implements the onDraw and the onCreate(Context context) methods (I won't copy the code as it's just that).

My guess is that Button is implementing a function that I'm not and that is why it is not drawing.

Any idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should add the code for your HeroCard seeing as how that is where your problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are not setting any params to your `HeroCard` view, it has no size, try to recover the params with `getLayoutParams()` and modify the width

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
hc.setWidth(200);
hc.setHeight(50);
```

In:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
HeroCard hc = new HeroCard(this);
HandLayout.addView(hc);
}
```

And check the output.

Comment: You said the same thing as the second answer, but technically the other answer is the correct one as it points out the problem. Thank you so very much anyways!